# VPS Server LAMP - Error establishing database connection

Tags: mysql, apache, server, lamp, vps

I have wordpress on LAMP server then often is down.
The error message is "Error establishing database connection". I don't know why!
User and password of db are correct, if I restart ALL server all works again.

the VPS have 2GB of ram.
I upgrade php limit in php.ini on 1024M and in wordpress config

I don't understand why server always breaks, please help me!
Here the syslog:

```
   /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime))
Sep 29 11:29:02 vps142555 -- MARK --
Sep 29 11:32:01 vps142555 /USR/SBIN/CRON[6000]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep 29 11:39:01 vps142555 /USR/SBIN/CRON[6004]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime))
Sep 29 11:59:33 vps142555 -- MARK --
Sep 29 12:09:01 vps142555 /USR/SBIN/CRON[6024]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime))
Sep 29 12:32:01 vps142555 /USR/SBIN/CRON[6048]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep 29 12:37:06 vps142555 kernel: [2410889.511488] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 1996 (mysqld) score 0 vm:488652kB, rss:67976kB, swap:39012kB
Sep 29 12:37:08 vps142555 kernel: [2410891.904013] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 4997 (apache2) score 0 vm:238648kB, rss:47692kB, swap:2812kB
Sep 29 12:37:11 vps142555 mysqld_safe: Number of processes running now: 0
Sep 29 12:37:11 vps142555 mysqld_safe: mysqld restarted
Sep 29 12:37:13 vps142555 kernel: [2410895.275214] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 5978 (apache2) score 0 vm:240468kB, rss:49756kB, swap:2460kB
Sep 29 12:37:14 vps142555 kernel: [2410896.933917] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 5976 (apache2) score 0 vm:238232kB, rss:47720kB, swap:2672kB
Sep 29 12:37:13 vps142555 mysqld: 160929 12:37:13 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
Sep 29 12:37:14 vps142555 mysqld: 160929 12:37:14 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
Sep 29 12:37:14 vps142555 mysqld: 160929 12:37:14 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
Sep 29 12:37:14 vps142555 mysqld: 160929 12:37:14 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
Sep 29 12:37:14 vps142555 mysqld: 160929 12:37:14 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
Sep 29 12:37:14 vps142555 mysqld: 160929 12:37:14 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
Sep 29 12:37:14 vps142555 mysqld: 160929 12:37:14 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
Sep 29 12:37:15 vps142555 kernel: [2410897.519920] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 5941 (apache2) score 0 vm:236836kB, rss:30424kB, swap:17708kB
Sep 29 12:37:14 vps142555 mysqld: 160929 12:37:14 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
Sep 29 12:37:15 vps142555 kernel: [2410898.744883] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 5955 (apache2) score 0 vm:232268kB, rss:23744kB, swap:22364kB
Sep 29 12:37:16 vps142555 kernel: [2410899.545623] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 6061 (apache2) score 0 vm:230300kB, rss:38016kB, swap:6004kB
Sep 29 12:37:16 vps142555 mysqld: 160929 12:37:16 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Sep 29 12:37:17 vps142555 kernel: [2410900.015311] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 6062 (apache2) score 0 vm:227740kB, rss:34284kB, swap:7128kB
Sep 29 12:37:17 vps142555 kernel: [2410900.690501] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 5980 (apache2) score 0 vm:222252kB, rss:30612kB, swap:6816kB
Sep 29 12:37:17 vps142555 mysqld: 160929 12:37:17 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
Sep 29 12:37:17 vps142555 mysqld: InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 2365452992
Sep 29 12:37:17 vps142555 mysqld: 160929 12:37:17  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
Sep 29 12:37:17 vps142555 mysqld: InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
Sep 29 12:37:17 vps142555 mysqld: InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
Sep 29 12:37:18 vps142555 mysqld: InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
Sep 29 12:37:18 vps142555 mysqld: InnoDB: buffer...
Sep 29 12:37:18 vps142555 kernel: [2410901.336589] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 5977 (apache2) score 0 vm:222000kB, rss:14816kB, swap:21748kB
Sep 29 12:37:18 vps142555 kernel: [2410901.723385] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 6057 (apache2) score 0 vm:222544kB, rss:30148kB, swap:6068kB
Sep 29 12:37:18 vps142555 mysqld: InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 2365502829
Sep 29 12:37:19 vps142555 kernel: [2410902.245687] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 6071 (apache2) score 0 vm:223576kB, rss:34220kB, swap:3200kB
Sep 29 12:37:19 vps142555 kernel: [2410903.117311] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 6335 (mysqld) score 0 vm:344240kB, rss:38588kB, swap:0kB
Sep 29 12:37:20 vps142555 kernel: [2410903.724624] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 6077 (apache2) score 0 vm:223832kB, rss:29632kB, swap:7960kB
Sep 29 12:37:20 vps142555 kernel: [2410904.218604] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 6064 (apache2) score 0 vm:222544kB, rss:23472kB, swap:12720kB
Sep 29 12:37:21 vps142555 kernel: [2410904.505518] OOM killer in rage, 1 tasks killed
Sep 29 12:37:21 vps142555 kernel: [2410904.505694] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 6073 (apache2) score 0 vm:222544kB, rss:23692kB, swap:12588kB
Sep 29 12:37:21 vps142555 mysqld_safe: mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
Sep 29 12:37:22 vps142555 kernel: [2410905.456095] OOM killer in rage, 2 tasks killed
Sep 29 12:37:22 vps142555 kernel: [2410905.456283] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 6074 (apache2) score 0 vm:222544kB, rss:24760kB, swap:11536kB
Sep 29 12:37:23 vps142555 kernel: [2410906.469929] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 6078 (apache2) score 0 vm:222544kB, rss:29304kB, swap:7268kB
Sep 29 12:37:23 vps142555 kernel: [2410906.972042] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 6081 (apache2) score 0 vm:221256kB, rss:27988kB, swap:7444kB
Sep 29 12:37:24 vps142555 kernel: [2410907.732515] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 6099 (apache2) score 0 vm:223576kB, rss:27932kB, swap:9608kB
Sep 29 12:37:26 vps142555 kernel: [2410909.311145] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 6080 (apache2) score 0 vm:222588kB, rss:27872kB, swap:8680kB
Sep 29 12:37:27 vps142555 kernel: [2410910.762627] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 6090 (apache2) score 0 vm:223832kB, rss:25812kB, swap:11936kB
Sep 29 12:37:29 vps142555 kernel: [2410912.842178] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 6089 (apache2) score 0 vm:224084kB, rss:32840kB, swap:5748kB
Sep 29 12:37:30 vps142555 kernel: [2410913.865956] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 6087 (apache2) score 0 vm:223832kB, rss:29124kB, swap:8940kB
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sep 29 12:37:14 vps142555 mysqld: 160929 12:37:14 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
Sep 29 12:37:15 vps142555 kernel: [2410898.744883] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 5955 (apache2) score 0 vm:232268kB, rss:23744kB, swap:22364kB
Sep 29 12:37:16 vps142555 kernel: [2410899.545623] Out of memory in UB 142555: OOM killed process 6061 (apache2) score 0 vm:230300kB, rss:38016kB, swap:6004kB
```

Look at the log

Kernel has killed mysqld because it does not have memory to allocate for innodb buffer pool. Check who is eating memory.

Because kernel has stoped mysql that's why connection issue is showing.

Comment: How I can do that?

Comment: use top or http://www.binarytides.com/linux-command-check-memory-usage/

Comment: https://s17.postimg.org/fkxgsbdxb/sas.jpg
Look Top, is all quite. Ram is empty of process

Comment: Can you get the list of cron

Comment: "No crontab for roots"

Comment: Let's discuss more in details. Do you have changed anything previously. Is there it only dedicated to MySQL.

Comment: Why you have added 1024M in php.ini

Comment: There was a singular bug in php version and all was in out of memory.
I upgrade a php version and solved that.
TKS

Answer (score 0):

There was a singular bug in php version and all was in out of memory.
I upgrade a php version and solved that.
TKS